# Using SSL with a .net remote endpoint without IIS

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, remoting

I have setup a vanilla .net remote endpoint. It is behind a load balancer that handles SSL traffic so all the server side endpoint sees is plain old TCP traffic. The client configuration needs to be set up to connect to the load balancer over SSL.

The whole point of this exercise is to remove IIS from the technology stack.

What should the client configuration be? or is this even possible?

Comment: What is your question, and didn't you ask it earlier today?

Comment: Where's the question? You have an error doing this? You looking for confirmation?